# CF: What is the difference between M and MB?

Tags: cloud-foundry

From the [Cloud Foundry Documentation](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/manifest.html#memory):

> memory Use the memory attribute to specify the memory limit for all
>   instances of an app. This attribute requires a unit of measurement: **M**,
>   **MB**, **G**, or **GB**, in upper case or lower case.

Can someone define the difference between **M** vs **MB** and **G** vs **GB**?

Initially I thought M is just MB and G is just GB. But my issue in Predix was resolved when I used MB instead of M. I wish to understand the significance

Answer (score 1):

No difference. M and MB are megabytes, G and GB are gigabytes.

Comment: Initially that's what I thought. I am asking this because M caused problems and MB fixed it somehow so there's definitely something that separates M from MB

Comment: Please submit an issue (https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cli/issues/new) if it's not working as expected so we can fix it.  
"memory: 64M" in my app manifest works as expected.

Comment: "memory: 64M" would also work on another environment that we have that's why I need to understand the difference between M and MB/ G and GB. I wish to know why instead of getting satisfied just because it worked.

Comment: Look at the code: `cf push` uses regexp `(?i)^(-?\d+)([KMGT])B?$` to parse your input. It then only looks at the 2nd group , i.e. ([KMGT]), and ignores any optional "B" suffix, in calculating the memory in bytes. 
https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cli/blob/ffee70cca68ab15df71f48641f6fa3bb007c4a2b/cf/formatters/bytes.go#L77,  
https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cli/blob/ffee70cca68ab15df71f48641f6fa3bb007c4a2b/cf/formatters/bytes.go#L61

Comment: It appears that they should be the same. Thanks for pointing to the github repo. I hope this is the same code that's currently in Predix Basic.